How to target .NET Framework 4.0 in VS 2022 on Windows 11?
When I try to open a solution in Visual Studio 2022 that contains projects targeting .NET 4.0, I get an option to download the .NET 4.0 targeting pack. When I try to download it using the download option, it tells me that it's already installed. How do I get VS2022 to recognise that .NET 4.0 is installed?


Download the reference assembly for .net40 from NuGet -https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net40/



rename the NuGet package downloaded as a .zip and extract it
copy paste the content of the folder build.NETFramework\ into Program files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework.


This saved me. The other way that top in MS help site is download 2019, but the site for older download is blocked or out of order for me.
Noted that even though in the .NETFramework folder there's already a 4.0 folder but you will need to overwrite it.
Somehow, all the data is there, MS just blocked the ability to target and build in 4.0. I hear it the same 4.5 -_-. There still are alot of legacy programs out there why make it so hard?
